# jQuery document.ready + Asp.Net ContentPlaceholder cause Visual Studio intellisence problems

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I want to execute JavaScript when document is ready without much syntax overhead. The idea is to use `Site.Master` and `ContentPlaceholder`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="OnReadyScript" runat="server" />
    });
</script>
```

and in inherited pages just write plain code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="OnReadyScript" runat="server">
    $("#Login").focus();
</asp:Content>
```

It works fine but Visual Studio complains and gives warnings.

Warning in master page is `Expected expression` at the line `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder`.

In inherited pages warning is `Could not find 'OnReadyScript' in the current master page or pages.`

I tried using `Writer.Write` in master page to render `script` tag and wrapping code:

```
<% Writer.Write(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(document).ready(function () {"); %>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="OnReadyScrit" runat="server" />
<% Writer.Write(@"});"); %>
```

but page rendering terminates after opening script tag is rendered. Html basically ends with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Visual Studio's syntax highlighting.

Try

```
<%= @"<script type=""text/javascript"">$(document).ready(function () {" %>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="OnReadyScript" runat="server" />
<%= @"});" %>
```

Comment: Same as with `Writer.Write` - rendering terminates after opening `script` tag. `$(document)...` does not get rendered. Looks like there is some kind of built-in protection from JavaScript injection in Asp.Net.